# Как начать участие

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, я новичок.Я бы хотел узнать, как общаться с участники, комментировать ответы.Больше одного раза написать ответ у меня не получается.Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Добро пожаловать. Будем рады видеть Вас в числе активных участников. Задавайте вопросы, пишите ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё подробно расписано в [СПРАВКЕ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/faq/#heading13). Комментировать чужие ответы вы сможете после того как наберёте 50 очков репутации (1-2 хороших ответа), свои - уже сейчас.

Отвечать на один и тот же вопрос можно лишь единожды, но ответ свой, можно дополнять неограниченное количество раз.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечать можно один раз, это нормально.
Для того, чтобы комментировать ответы, надо набрать определенное число баллов "уважения".

Организационные вопросы лучше задавать на мете.
meta://russ.hashcode.ru
(+)
//================= 28.07.2015
Здесь многое изменилось.
Ответы можно давать более одного и новый адрес 
https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/